# GCS - Internet Egress Costs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Does anyone know where can I find the pricing for Google Cloud Storage pricing for Internet Traffic?

Doing some design work and I need to work out what the cost of multiple GCS Buckets serving content to the Internet may cost and having trouble finding it a definitive resource on the cost Per GB of egress traffic.

This page has a lot of information but for some reason Internet isn't mentioned: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet access falls under [General network usage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-egress). Pricing starts at $0.12 per GB and varies based upon destination.